# multiply a column by a number in pandas skip or make it zeros if the column does not exists

Tags: python, pandas

So I have table whuich I created a pivot from
After the pivot I made the index, columns and used one of the column values as columns from which the expected counts are represented. I'd like to multiply each column(values turn columns) to a figure, but because some of the values were not created at that point in time, the column with the specified name did not appear; making the multiplication process run into errors, is there a way I could skip that error or make the the column be Created but show zeros after the multiplication, in cases where the values are not in the converted column

df

```
**Name Fruit**  
Jane Apple 
Celi Banana 
Pete Mango
Fred grape
```

pivot

```
Name Apple Banana   Mango   grape 
Jane  1      0        0      0
Celi  0      1        0      0
Pete  0      0        1      0
Fred  0      0        0      1



pivot['total']=(pivot['Apple '].multiply(14)+ 
                pivot['Banana ].multiply(110)+
                 pivot['Mango'].multiply(18)+
                 pivot['grape].multiply(10)+
                 pivot['peach].multiply(140))
```

Expected this:

```
Name Apple Banana   Mango   grape  total
Jane  1      0        0       0      14
Celi  0      1        0       0      110
Pete  0      0        1       0      18
Fred  0      0        0       1      10
```

But getting errors due to peach not being in the values. is there a way I could skip that error or make the the column be Created but show zeros after the multiplication, in cases where the values are not in the converted column . Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: what is your pivot code?

Comment: @jezrael pivot=pd.pivot(df, index=['Name'], values='Fruit', columns='Fruit', aggfunc={'Fruit':'count'}, fill_value=0)
pivot=pivot.reset_index(level=0)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with mapping columns names:

```
d = {'Apple':14,'Banana':110,'Mango':18,'grape':10,'peach':140}

df1 = pivot.select_dtypes(np.number)
pivot['total'] = df1.dot(df1.columns.map(d).fillna(0))
#alternative solution
#pivot['total'] = df1.mul(df1.columns.map(d).fillna(0)).sum(axis=1)
print (pivot)
   Name  Apple  Banana  Mango  grape  total
0  Jane      1       0      0      0     14
1  Celi      0       1      0      0    110
2  Pete      0       0      1      0     18
3  Fred      0       0      0      1     10
```

Or with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for helper column and then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
d = {'Apple':14,'Banana':110,'Mango':18,'grape':10,'peach':140}
pivot = (df.assign(new = df['Fruit'].map(d))
           .pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Fruit', values='new', aggfunc='sum'))
```

Comment: Tried replicating, but throws in an error, which is quite tricky to resolve-- 
 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @Dela - If use `pivot['total'] = df1.mul(df1.columns.map(d).fillna(0)).sum(axis=1)` got same erorr?

Comment: Yes, both give same error